# DataPoint LabelFormat

Tags: c++, charts, datapoint

I got this code simplified that display very well my data in my chart but the problem is that i want to display a label RIGHT next to all the points so it looks like something [this](http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b586/mati22mat/Capturem_zpsfdece65c.png). For now it's like [this](http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b586/mati22mat/Capture_zps7dd707db.png) and it looks ugly.

The documentation of LabelFormat on MSDN and others are not really helpful.

```
[...]
System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::DataPoint^ a_point;
System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^ series1 =
    (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series());

for (i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
{
    a_point = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::DataPoint());
    a_point->SetValueXY(X[i], Y[i]);
    a_point->Label = i.ToString();
    a_point->LabelForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Gray;
    a_point->LabelFormat = ""; // here

    series1->Points->Add(a_point);
}

Series->Add(series1);
[...]
```

Comment: It could also possibly be: a_point->LabelToolTip = "?";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the smart labels on the serie.

```
series1->SmartLabelStyle->Enabled = false;
```